# Binary Trees Unlabelled Nodes

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Number of Binary trees that can be formed using 3 unlabelled nodes.

Answer on several places is 5.

But according to me answer should be 1 because all the trees that we will make using three nodes will be isomorphic.

Comment: maybe you're thinking of complete trees, but three nodes in a line are also a binary tree.

Answer (score 0):

The number of trees made from n nodes are equal to the nth [catalan number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).

More precisely here is recursive equation for the trees formed :-

```
T(n) = sum(T(i)*T(n-1-i)) where i in (0,n-1)
```

**Example :-**

> consider binary trees of 5 nodes.
>
> 1. keeping one as root we can divide rest 4 into subtrees a follows
>
>    (1,3),(2,2),(3,1) where first tupple is left subtree and 2nd right
>      subtree
> 2. You can further have different arrange of the subtrees hence :-
>
>    T(5) = T(1)*T(3) + T(2)*T(2) + T(3)*T(1)
> 3. Above method can be generalized to the recurrence relations given above which can be evaluated as catalan numbers using advance
>      mathematics

**Your Example : -**

> ```
> T(3) = T(1)*T(1) + T(2)*T(0) + T(0)*T(2)
>
> As T(2) = 2 (1 right aligned & 1 left aligned tree)   and T(1) = 1 , T(0) = 1
>
> T(3) = 1*1 + 2*1 + 1*2 = 5
> ```

Comment: Please explain it logically.

Comment: @user3288929 check my example